# How to write a JSON endpoint in Yesod which receives file/image uploads?

Tags: json, ajax, haskell, file-upload, yesod

I see a lot of posts that involve writing a form widget to handle image uploads, but my Yesod server is just a JSON API.  I would be receiving the Post request via Angular File Upload.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple way of doing this is to encode the file as base64 data and
then send it as part of JSON. But the disadvantage of this method is
that it increases the data size.

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
{- stack
     --resolver lts-6.24
     --install-ghc
     runghc
     --package yesod
     --package yesod-core
     --package persistent
     --package text
     --package aeson
     --package bytestring
     --package base64-bytestring
-}

{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances#-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings#-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Control.Monad (join)
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Text (Text, unpack)
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy.Encoding
import Data.Typeable (Typeable)
import Text.Blaze.Html.Renderer.Utf8 (renderHtml)
import Yesod
import Data.Aeson
import Data.Aeson.Types
import qualified Data.ByteString as BS
import Data.ByteString (ByteString)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Base64 as BS
import qualified Data.Text.Encoding as T

data App = App

mkYesod
  "App"
  [parseRoutes|
/json/test TestR POST
|]

instance Yesod App where
  approot = ApprootStatic "http://localhost:3006"

instance RenderMessage App FormMessage where
  renderMessage _ _ = defaultFormMessage

data Test = Test {
      fileData :: Text,
      name :: String
} deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)

instance FromJSON Test where
    parseJSON (Object v) = Test <$>
                           v .: "fileData" <*>
                           v .: "name"
    parseJSON _ = empty

postTestR :: Handler TypedContent
postTestR = do
  testData :: Test <- requireJsonBody
  let fileData' = BS.decode (T.encodeUtf8 $ fileData testData)
  case fileData' of
    Left err -> error err
    Right dat -> liftIO $ BS.writeFile "/home/sibi/myfile" dat
  selectRep $ provideRep $ return emptyObject

main :: IO ()
main = warp 3006 App
```

On execution:

```
$ curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -X POST -d '{"fileData":"aGVsbG8gd29ybGQ=","name":"Filename"}' http://127.0.0.1:3006/json/test
$ cat /home/sibi/myfile
hello world
```